# Is it possible to fix a "knob twist" bath plug without spares?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, cord-and-plug

A little while ago the knob fell off my bath plug assembly. It's one of those where there's no chain - the knob sits in front of the overflow and you twist it to pop the plug up.

I couldn't find the correct replacement so I ordered a "universal" one that wasn't - it was too small to fit on the little projection in the middle of the overflow. So I filed the aperture down a bit to try and make it bigger.

It was almost small enough but not quite - and in trying to force it on, the whole assembly seemed to collapse. The little projection disappeared behind the overflow and now the plug won't "pop" anymore at all.

I'd need to take the side of the bath off to take a look, and it's not coming easily. I'm concerned about doing it at this time when I can't just go out to replace it.

I have no idea what the assembly look a like behind there, so I don't know whether it's literally bust and needs spares to fix or whether I've just pushed it out of alignment and a bit of wiggling will get it back.

Does anyone know whether this is likely to be worth attempting?

Answer (score 1):

A coat hanger will usually retrieve it , the “stopper” is a hollow tube that slides up and down to block the flow. I have used a coat hanger to pull the assembly up through the overflow tube many times. You can remove the stopper until you get the correct piece or just use the hanger to pull it up and down until you get the right piece.  I would take the pieces to a specialty plumbing store they probably have parts to fix it.